# TeamCity - run build without attached triggers

Tags: teamcity

I have build config A and B. A is triggered daily at a specific time. B is triggered by successful build result from A.

Is it possible to run A manually without automatically triggering B?

Currently I have to create C which is a copy of A and run it instead. Under the hood it's all the same as A.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pause build B before running A.